# How to prove that, if $A$ and $B$ are vectors, then their cross product is still a vector?

Tags: reference-frames, vectors, representation-theory, rotation

in my course of special relativity we are introducing tensors: however, before doing that, my professor sort of re-defined vectors saying that in a 3D euclidean space, $A$ can be called a vector if, under a rotation, it transforms like the coordinates.
So, if
$$x_i'=R_{ij}x_j$$
where $R$ is the rotation matrix and it satisfies $R^TR=RR^T=1$ (I'm calling $1$ the identity matrix), then $A$ is a vector if
$$A_i'=R_{ij}A_j$$
Now, he told us to try to prove that, if $A$ and $B$ are vectors, then the cross product $V=A\times B$ is a vector too.

I know I should get the following:
$$V_i'=R_{ij}V_j=R_{ij}(\varepsilon_{jlm}A_lB_m)$$
My professor also told us that the following identity is true:
$$\varepsilon_{abc}R_{aj}R_{bk}R_{cm}=det(R)\varepsilon_{jkm}$$
This is what I've done:
$$V_i'=(\varepsilon_{ijk}A_jB_k)'=\varepsilon_{ijk}A_j'B_k'=\varepsilon_{ijk}(R_{jl}A_l)(R_{km}B_m)$$
I have no idea how I should apply the identity my professor gave us and I don't know where that "third matrix" comes from.

Comment: Your question is related, although not coinciding,  to this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/677386/passive-transformation-pseudo-vectors-and-cross-product

Comment: The subsections [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Handedness) note some subtleties.

Comment: @J.G. thank you! From your link I was able to find an answer to my question